# How to run webdriver tests on docker firefox-standalone-debug container instead of regular firefox browser

Tags: selenium, ubuntu, docker, jenkins, webdriver

I have a regular ***Firefox*** installed on my Linux ***Ubuntu*** as well as ***docker-firefox-standalone-debug*** container. Moreover I have ***Xfvb*** and I set ***DISPLAY*** overthere. Now when I run my *Webdriver* test from Jenkins everything works fine and my test runs on regular ***Firefox***. But the problem is that I would like to start my test now on ***docker-firefox-standalone-debug*** container. Can anyone tell me how to force my test on Jenkins to run on docker? By default it starts on regular ***Firefox*** and I don't now how to tell him yo run on ***docker-firefox-debug***?

Comment: Hello I can give you the example in Java. Is it OK?

Answer (score 3):

You'll need to use the remote web driver instead of the regular WebDriver.

For example if you run your conatiner as follows:

```sh
docker run -d -p 4444:4444 selenium/standalone-firefox-debug
```

Use the follwing code:

```java
RemoteWebDriver driver = new RemoteWebDriver(
                    new URL("http://localhost:4444/wd/hub"),
                    DesiredCapabilities.firefox());
```

Instead of:

```java
WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
```

Regards

Comment: please see my answer - I still get an error. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I run:

> docker run -d -p 32780:4444 -p 5999:5900 selenium/standalone-firefox-debug

so when I type

> docker ps

I have

> 6b7fa91575ae        selenium/standalone-firefox-debug              "/opt/bin/entry_point"   8 seconds ago       Up 6 seconds        0.0.0.0:32780->4444/tcp, 0.0.0.0:5999->5900/tcp

then in my code:

```
RemoteWebDriver driver = new RemoteWebDriver( 
                                new URL("http://192.168.99.100:32780/wd/hub"), 
                                DesiredCapabilities.firefox());
```

This works :)

Comment: Don't use -P use instead -p 4444:4444 because the port will change each time you run the container and you will need to change your code